# Cypress Test Runner stuck on new url

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to run cypress script, which is login the user, now after login, app navigates from one URL to another, while URL is navigated successfully, but Test runner is continuously in 'New URL' state.

Check Screenshot:
[image]

I am using following code:

```
describe('Login', function(){
    it('Login Successfully', function(){
        const urlRedirects = [];
        cy.visit('https://vep-staging.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=2bu8f0pfkqaasa8jjatgd8d40g&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.staging.showcare.io%2Fproduct-showcase&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=254805b5dfbc4f68acbdb28add5536a4&code_challenge=NvfTn44X98LyNBBCJoAdDPHADnHLbiuy0gj2Xcg6Mow&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query')
        cy.get('.modal-dialog')
        cy.get('#signInFormUsername', { timeout: 10000 }).eq(0).type('email_address', { force: true })
        cy.get('#signInFormPassword').eq(0).type('password', { force: true })
        cy.get('[name="signInSubmitButton"]').eq(0).click({ force: true }).wait(1000)
        .then(() => {
          cy.location().should((loc) => {
            expect(loc.pathname).to.eq('/product-showcase')
          }).wait(4000)
        cy.reload();
        cy.get('a').eq(0).trigger('mouseover').click({ force: true })

        })
        
    })
})
```

Comment: Is your test failing at this line `cy.get('a').eq(0).trigger('mouseover').click({ force: true })` ?

Comment: @AlapanDas No, its not.. Its passed, but it's running

Comment: Can you remove `cy.reload` and try again. I guess this is causing the issue.

Comment: nope, That wasn't necessary, but things worked out @AlapanDas

Comment: But problem now is that I am unable to click that 'Exhibitor Access' button.